# Change of dependent variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am hoping to evaluate the integral

$$ \int_0 ^R u(r,t)r^2\,dr$$

However, I do not have an expression for $u$, but rather $\tau(r,t)$, where the two are related by

$$\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial u} = f(u)$$

with $f(u)$ known.  Unfortunately, $u$ cannot readily be calculated from the above.  Is there a way to calculate the original integral without first finding $u$?  Thanks all.

Comment: Plz give the type of functions $ \tau$ and f are it will help to think in a particular direction

Comment: We can let $f(u) = A + Bu$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants, and we can let $\tau$ be the finite power series $\tau(r,t) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n(t)r^n$ for given functions $a_n(t)$.